Cached view file does not exist, but only for one user
Having a bizarre issue where Laravel is unable to find a cached view file, but it only affects a single user out of dozens. Everybody else is able to use the website fine, but for this lone user they get these errors.
[2024-06-30 14:05:16] production.ERROR: fopen(/var/www/project/storage/framework/cache/data/aa/55/aa55bc11003569771d7e3a092e3a751da2da1ab0): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"userId":7,"exception":"[o
bject] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(/var/www/project/storage/framework/cache/data/aa/55/aa55bc11003569771d7e3a092e3a751da2da1ab0): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory at /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/fr
amework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php:69)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(255): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\{closure}()
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php(69): fopen()
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/LockableFile.php(42): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\LockableFile->createResource()
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php(108): Illuminate\\Filesystem\\LockableFile->__construct()
#5 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(317): Illuminate\\Cache\\FileStore->add()
#6 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php(135): Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository->add()
#7 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php(116): Illuminate\\Cache\\RateLimiter->increment()
#8 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(156): Illuminate\\Cache\\RateLimiter->hit()
#9 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(125): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#10 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(87): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#11 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#12 /var/www/project/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): App\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#14 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(805): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#16 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(784): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#17 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(748): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#18 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(737): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#19 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#20 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Http/Middleware/ServeNova.php(23): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Laravel\\Nova\\Http\\Middleware\\ServeNova->handle()
#23 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#25 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#26 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#28 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#29 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#30 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#31 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#32 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#33 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#34 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#35 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#36 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(183): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#37 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(119): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#38 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#39 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#40 /var/www/project/public/index.php(58): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#41 {main}
"}

I confirmed that that cache file does not exist in the filesystem.
Also, running these commands has no effect:
artisan view:clear
artisan cache:clear
artisan view:cache

The storage directory is writable by www-data
